# When changing UITextField property isSecureTextEntry for the first time keyboard flashes

Tags: ios, uitextfield

When I change UITextField property `isSecureTextEntry`, the keyboards flashes.
But this happens only if once per app launch. Any ideas why and how to fix?

Code I am using is relatively simple, textField is inside tableViewCell, there is some setup method:

```
field.keyboardType   = input.key.configuration.keybordType
field.textContentType = input.key.configuration.context
field.autocapitalizationType = input.key.configuration.capitalization
textField.isSecureTextEntry = input.key.configuration.isSecure
field.text = input.value
```

And then I toggle like this

```
field.isSecureTextEntry.toggle()
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use like this

```
textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
```

Comment: Updated my snippet, I am aware how to make it secure. That's not the issue. Issue is that when switching between secure and not secure keyboard flashes